# Program stops after cin - C++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I know this might be a duplicate to another question on this forum but I couldn't find the solution for my problem, even if I searched for like 1 hour.
The problem is that my program stops after the 4th "cin". I don't know why, I tried everything: "cin.ingore(); cin.clear();", "cin.get();".
Could someone help me please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct elev
{
    char nume[20];
    vector<int> note_info;
    float medie;
};

int main()
{
    int n, e = 0;
    vector<elev> elevi;

    cout << "n = "; cin >> n;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int s = 0, nr;

        elevi.push_back(elev());

        cout << "Nume elev: "; cin >> elevi[i].nume;
        cout << "Numar note informatica: "; cin >> nr;

        for (int j = 0; j < nr; j++)
        {
            int temp;
            cout << "Nota nr. " << j + 1 << ": "; cin >> temp;
            elevi[i].note_info.push_back(temp);
            s += temp;
        }

        elevi[i].medie = (float)(s / nr);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (elevi[j].medie != elevi[j + 1].medie)
            {
                e += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++)
            {
                if (elevi[j].medie < elevi[j + 1].medie)
                {
                    elev temp = elevi[j];
                    elevi[j] = elevi[j + 1];
                    elevi[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++)
            {
                if (elevi[j].nume > elevi[j + 1].nume)
                {
                    elev temp = elevi[j];
                    elevi[j] = elevi[j + 1];
                    elevi[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Rezultate:";

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << '\n' << elevi[i].nume << ' ' << setprecision(2) << fixed << elevi[i].medie;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have an access to index out of bounds on the first iteration of the cycle. Note that vector indices are zero based.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev it worked!!! Thanks man! I didn't know that a mistake this little could ruin everything. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, extracting from `cin` to a raw `char*` pointer is not safe, since you might run past the end of valid storage. Recommend using `std::string` instead of `char[20]`. And if you want that input to be able to include spaces, use `getline(cin, str)` instead of `>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
```

The error stems from trying to access the vector `elevi` at a position it doesn't yet have. Because vectors start indexing at `0`, the first access made to `elevi` should be at index 0.